# to Apache 2.4.4 and Tomcat 7.0.33. Accessing the website via HTTPS produces “Object not found” error

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

Issue: Upgraded to Apache 2.4.4 and Tomcat 7.0.33. Accessing the website via HTTPS produces “Object not found” error.
The error logs show no errors (apche, tomcat, or Windows).
Server OS: Windows 2008
Apache: version 2.4.4
Tomcat: version 7.033
JRE: version 1.6.0_43

Httpd.conf

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
# mod_jk setup
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/mod_jk.log.%Y-%m-%d.txt 86400"
JkLogLevel error
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
# Should mod_jk send SSL information to Tomcat (default is On)
JkExtractSSL On
# What is the indicator for SSL (default is HTTPS)
JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS
# What is the indicator for SSL session (default is SSL_SESSION_ID)
JkSESSIONIndicator SSL_SESSION_ID
# What is the indicator for client SSL cipher suit (default is SSL_CIPHER)
JkCIPHERIndicator SSL_CIPHER
# What is the indicator for the client SSL certificated (default is SSL_CLIENT_CERT)
JkCERTSIndicator SSL_CLIENT_CERT 

<Directory "N:/Prod/WebApp_Tomcat/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location /*/WEB-INF/*>
deny from all
</Location>
JkMount /WebApp/* presentation
</IfModule>
# end of mod_jk setup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL virtual method does not work in our environment. Recreating the http-ssl.conf file as follows solved our problem.

http-ssl.conf

```
##
##  SSL Global Context
##
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLEngine On
SSLOptions +StrictRequire

<Directory "C:/WebApp">
SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/WebApp_Tomcat">
SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
SSLSessionCache         "shmcb:C:/ApacheGroup/Apache2.4.4/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLProxyEngine off
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" ssl-unclean-shutdown
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/SSL.log.%Y-%m-%d.txt 86400"

LogLevel warn

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log.txt \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</IfModule>
```